# Can't get NumberRangeFilter to work in my Google Chart

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm trying to figure out why my range-filter isn't working out or not even showing up in my graph. I tried to look into Google Charts doc, but for some reason I'm not sure if I'm doing this the right way. What I want is that you can sort out data, by the category filter which works fine. But I also want to filter the range (slider) to see specific data in that year.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WaUu2/309/)

HTML

```
<div id="rangeFilter_div"></div>
<div id="colFilter_div"></div>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['controls']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Foo');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Bar');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Baz');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Cad');
    data.addRows([
        ['2005',  45, 60, 89, 100],
        ['2006',  155, 50, 79, 24],
        ['2007',  35, 31, 140, 53],
        ['2008',  105, 23, 43, 82],
        ['2009',  120, 56, 21, 67],
        ['2010',  65, 19, 34, 134],
        ['2011',  80, 23, 130, 40],
        ['2012',  70, 140, 83, 90]
    ]);

    var columnsTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    columnsTable.addColumn('number', 'colIndex');
    columnsTable.addColumn('string', 'colLabel');
    var initState= {selectedValues: []};
    // put the columns into this data table (skip column 0)
    for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        columnsTable.addRow([i, data.getColumnLabel(i)]);
        // you can comment out this next line if you want to have a default selection other than the whole list
        initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(i));
    }
    // you can set individual columns to be the default columns (instead of populating via the loop above) like this:
    // initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(4));

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'LineChart',
        containerId: 'chart_div',
        dataTable: data,
        options: {
            title: 'Foobar',
            width: 600,
            height: 400
        }
    });

    var columnFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'colFilter_div',
        dataTable: columnsTable,
        options: {
            filterColumnLabel: 'colLabel',
            ui: {
                label: 'Columns',
                allowTyping: false,
                allowMultiple: true,
                allowNone: false,
                selectedValuesLayout: 'belowStacked'
            }
        },
        state: initState
    });

    var rangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
        containerId: 'rangeFilter_div',
        dataTable: columnsTable,
        options: {
            filterColumnLabel: 'Year',
            ui: {
                showRangeValues: true,
                label: true
            }
        }
    });

    function setChartView () {
        var state = columnFilter.getState();
        var row;
        var view = {
            columns: [0]
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < state.selectedValues.length; i++) {
            row = columnsTable.getFilteredRows([{column: 1, value: state.selectedValues[i]}])[0];
            view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(row, 0));
        }
        // sort the indices into their original order
        view.columns.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a - b);
        });
        chart.setView(view);
        chart.draw();
    }
    google.visualization.events.addListener(columnFilter, 'statechange', setChartView);

    setChartView.bind(rangeFilter, chart);
    setChartView();
    columnFilter.draw();

}
```

Comment: You are almost there! Only problem is you are using `setChartView` instead of a dashboard, check documentation: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#using_controls_and_dashboards

Comment: @juvian, hells yes! I figured it out. lol